# Configure maven-war-plugin to use java 7

Tags: java, maven

I am getting the following error when building my project using maven-war-plugin even though I specify that it uses jdk 7 in the plugin configuration.

```
strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
```

Plugin configuration

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.2</version>
<configuration>
   <source>1.7</source>
   <target>1.7</target>
   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What source and target do you have for the maven-compiler-plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven WAR Plugin has no configuration for source/target. You have to configure [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html). There two possible solutions for this.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  [...]
</project>
```

and the other one is like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```